# xarray's scaling exponent is overlapping with the extended colorbar, how to shift the location of the displayed colorbar scaling exponent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-xarray, colorbar

In the below example, the `extend` option is enabled which then leads to the tip of the extended colorbar to be behind the exponent indicating the scaling of the values in the colorbar.

Which with a colormap with a dark upper limit leads to poor readability.

How can I move the scaling factor location just a bit upward?

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
z = np.arange(1,10) / 10_000
Z = np.outer(z,z)
da = xr.DataArray(Z, coords={"x":range(Z.shape[0]),"y":range(Z.shape[1])})
f, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=1, nrows=1)
da.plot(ax=axs,extend="both",cmap="inferno_r",cbar_kwargs={"label": "Hi", "shrink": 0.8, "aspect": 10})
f.tight_layout()
```

[image]

Comment: I think this only happens with tight layout? I think this is a matplotlib issue but I'm not sure how to fix either and would love to see if someone has a solution for this!

Comment: Hi, I just tried without tight layout, unfortunately the issue stayed. :-/